# Probability of limit superior of independent events proof

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I am trying to prove the following identity for a sequence of independent events $A_n$;

$$\mathbb{P}({\limsup_{n\to \infty} A_n})=1-\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{N\to\infty} \prod_{m=n}^N(1-\mathbb{P}(A_m))$$ 
but I am getting stuck:
\begin{align}\mathbb{P}(\limsup_{n\to\infty } A_{n})&=\mathbb{P}(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{m=n}^\infty A_m) \\&=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\mathbb{P}(\bigcup_{m=n}^\infty A_m) \\&=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\mathbb{P}\left(\left\{\bigcup_{m=n}^\infty A_m\right\}^c \right)\right) 
\\&=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcap_{m=n}^\infty A^c_m 
\right)\right)
\\&=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\prod_{m=n}^\infty \mathbb{P}\left(A^c_m 
\right)\right)
\\&=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\prod_{m=n}^\infty \left(1-\mathbb{P}(A_m)\right)\right)
\\&=\lim_{N\to \infty}\prod_{n=1}^N\left(1-\prod_{m=n}^\infty \left(1-\mathbb{P}(A_m)\right)\right)
\end{align}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
\begin{align*}
P(\limsup A_n)
&=1-P(\lim\inf A_n^c)\\
&=1-P(\cup_{n=1}^\infty\cap_{k=n}^\infty A_n^c)\\
&=1-\lim_{n\to\infty}P(\cap_{k=n}^\infty A_n^c)\tag{1}\\
&=1-\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{N\to\infty}P(\cap_{k=n}^NA_n^c)\tag{2}\\
&=1-\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{N\to\infty}\prod_{k=n}^n(1-P(A_n))\tag{3}
\end{align*}
$$
where in (1) we used measure continuity from below in (2) we used measure continuity from above and in (3) we used independence of the events $A_n$.